# Risk Management techniques in Agile project development

Tags: agile

I am currently doing a research study in Risk Management for Agile project development. As we know, there are a few steps involved in Risk Management in Agile project development, such as:

1. Agile Risk Identification
2. Agile Risk Analysis
3. Agile Risk Prioritisation
4. Agile Risk Responses
5. Agile Risk Resolution
6. Agile Risk Monitoring

But my question is: are there any specific techniques or tools used by the organizations to mitigate risks? If yes, can anyone share with me the available tools or techniques that can be used to mitigate the risks? Currently, I am still trying to understand the differences between Agile Risk Management and Traditional Risk Management.

Comment: I like the risk burndown chart for higher risk projects: https://www.mountaingoatsoftware.com/blog/managing-risk-on-agile-projects-with-the-risk-burndown-chart

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [list-generating questions are off-topic](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/23/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/).

Answer (score 3):

Many of the same techniques are used.  The agile philosophy and associated approaches directly address risk.

In traditional project management (PM) and software development life cycle (SDLC) much time and, therefore, cost are sunk into the Analysis, Requirements, Planning, and Design steps before any realizable value is created.  If, for whatever reason, the project is terminated then all of that is lost.  Testing is traditionally executed after Development is complete.  The longer the gap between the activities, the greater the impact: this ping-ponging of effort results in development having to revisit those items and delays planned work.  [Misunderstandings and miscommunications related to requirements](https://static.aminer.org/pdf/PDF/000/361/405/software_requirements_are_they_really_a_problem.pdf) are compounded by the layers and time between initial gathering and the delivery of the product; users express desires and wait for delivery.  Weekly status calls where workers report against a project plan are usually the only insight into progress.  postmortem conducted for *Lessons Learned* to be applied in the future is the only input for process improvement.

With an agile approach, once the purpose and vision is established, the work is done in incremental iterations that include all applicable aspects of the SDLC including testing.  Test first approaches also promote less waste by avoiding unnecessary work and helping to ensure needs are met.  When the organization needs to change priorities, i.e. seize a market opportunity, the completed work is releasable; there is little to no sunk cost to be lost.  User involvement and the expectation of change due to increased learning throughout the effort results in a more useful solution.  The continuous involvement of business people results in less delays and greater understanding of progress.  Having the work available ensure a more empirical measurement of effort and outcomes.  Regular inspection and retrospection for improving the way work is done is a key aspect of being agile.

Comment: Keep a RAID log

Answer (score -2):

> ...is [sic] there any specific techniques or tools used by the organizations to mitigate risks?

Yes.

> If yes, anyone [sic] can share with me the available tools or techniques that can be used to mitigate the risks?

Likely yes; however, tools and techniques are dependent on the threat being mitigated.  You will need to identify a few risks in order for anyone to share mitigating methods.

> Currently, i [sic] am still trying to understand the differences between agile risk management and traditional risk management.

There are none.

Comment: Interesting the negative votes with no comments.

Comment: Perhaps: "The are none."